# I need quotes and equal sign to show up in the DataElementName in an SSRS Report

Tags: xml, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that it's sole function is to output XML.  The XML has to be in exact in its format requirements. I have been able to manage all but two tags by using rectangles and text boxes,then going into the properties pane and setting the DataElementName to the needed name of the tag, and setting the DataElementStyle to 'Element'.  However, I have two tags, that need to be rendered with special characters equal sign (=) and quotation marks (" "). My problem, is that the DataElementName property does not allow for anything but letters, numbers and underscore characters.

I need the XML tag to render in this format:`<Part partCategory="BW">`
I also need the XML tag to render for the beginning of the report: `<Ffl version="3.3" xmlns:...`

Also of note, these two tags are not part of the data set, but only purpose is to meet the tag formatting requirements.

I have saved the report to XML, attempted to edit the two tags, but that didn't work but made a mess of the formatting.

Any help or suggestions will be welcome.